# Why does my overlay keep exceeding past my image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

My current image's overlay is exceeding the current size of the image. I initially changed the size of the image due to it being super big in comparison to what I need it for, and now the overlay is not working properly

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-5 order-md-2 text-center">
    <h2 class="title-dark">1957-1979</h2>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="../images/stanford_car.png" alt="Stanford Car" class="image-style">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-text">Stanford Car</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.image-style {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
}


.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.image-container:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

.overlay-text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The overlay is over the whole container which is larger than the image. Either shrink-wrap the container around the image or make the image 100% of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 options:

**Option 1: Adjust the width of the overlay as well**

The simplest solution is to simply give the `.overlay` class the same width as the `.image-style` (i.e., `width: 70%;`).

```
.image-style {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
}


.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    /* ... */
}
```

**Option 2: Give the `<img>` a set width**

The second options is to not specify the width of the image in terms of a percentage. You could give it something like `width: 1000px;` or whatever you want. Then, the problem will be that the container is still at a maximum width, so the overlay will still be too big, right? But now you can fix that by setting the `.image-container` width the `fit-content`.

```
.image-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
}

.image-style {
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```